# Finding partitions $\{A,B\}$ of the set $\mathbb N_n:=\{1,...,n\}$ such that $\Big|\prod_{i \in A}p_i-\prod_{i\in B}p_i\Big|=1$

Tags: number-theory, soft-question, prime-numbers

For a fixed $n$ , for what  partitions $\{A,B\}$ of the set $\mathbb N_n:=\{1,...,n\}$ do we have

$\Big|\prod_{i \in A}p_i-\prod_{i\in B}p_i\Big|=1$ ? , where $p_m$ denotes the $m$th prime for example $p_1=2,p_2=3...$ etc.

When the quantity is not $1$ , I can conclude that $p_{n+1} \le \Big|\prod_{i \in A}p_i-\prod_{i\in B}p_i\Big| $ this is why I am

interested in it . Also I would like to ask , for every integer $n>1$ does there exist a partition $\{A,B\}$

of  $\mathbb N_n:=\{1,...,n\}$ such that $\Big|\prod_{i \in A}p_i-\prod_{i\in B}p_i\Big|=1$ ? If not then for which $n$ there does not 
exist such a partition ?

Comment: This is related to (though not exactly the same thing as) Stormer's Theorem, for which see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Størmer's_theorem

Comment: Have you seen that I have posted an answer?

Comment: Earth to Souvik; come in, please.

Comment: @GerryMyerson : :) yes , I have seen your answer also upvoted it

Answer (score 1):

There is some information about this problem in Guy, Lacampagne, and Selfridge, Primes at a glance, Mathematics of Computation 48, #177 (January 1987) 183-202, available [here](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1987-48-177/S0025-5718-1987-0866108-3/S0025-5718-1987-0866108-3.pdf). See in particular Table 4, also the reference to D H Lehmer, On a problem of Stormer, Illinois J Math 8 (1964) 59-79, which should be available [here](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/illinois-journal-of-mathematics/volume-8/issue-1/On-a-problem-of-St%C3%B8rmer/10.1215/ijm/1256067456.full).

EDIT: Carl Pomerance, Ruth-Aaron numbers revisited, in the book, Paul Erdos and his Mathematics, 567-579, writes that it is conjectured that 714, 715 is the last pair of consecutive numbers whose product is the product of the first $k$ primes for some $k$. The paper is [here](https://math.dartmouth.edu/%7Ecarlp/PDF/paper130.pdf).